# How to disable some random days in MaterialDatePicker

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Like in title my dates will completly random, the user will deliver this dates. And I have question how to disable this dates in MaterialDatePicker ? It must be MaterialDatePicker cous of I want to keep possibility of selecting date in range. What i found is in Main you can use like:

```
MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker =
                        MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
                        .setCalendarConstraints(DaysOutOfValidate().build())
                        .setSelection(Pair.create(MaterialDatePicker.thisMonthInUtcMilliseconds(),MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds())).build();

                        materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "S");
```

than in main also:

```
  private CalendarConstraints.Builder DaysOutOfValidate() {

        List<Date> listDates = new ArrayList<>();
        listDates.add(new Date(2023,Calendar.NOVEMBER,10));
        listDates.add(new Date(2023,Calendar.NOVEMBER,16));

        CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilderRange = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
        constraintsBuilderRange.setValidator(new DaysOutOfValidate(listDates));
            Log.i("Inovked twice","Twice");

        return constraintsBuilderRange;
    }
```

next you write your ownValidator:

```
public class DaysOutOfValidate implements CalendarConstraints.DateValidator {

    int mYear, mMonth, mDayOfWeek;
    List<Date> dates;

    DaysOutOfValidate(int year, int month, int dayOfWeek) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = month;
        mDayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    }

    public DaysOutOfValidate(List<Date> dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    DaysOutOfValidate(Parcel parcel) {
        mYear = parcel.readInt();
        mMonth = parcel.readInt();
        mDayOfWeek = parcel.readInt();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isValid(long date) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(2023,Calendar.NOVEMBER,16);

        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.set(2023,Calendar.NOVEMBER,10);


        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.setTimeInMillis(date);

        Calendar[] calendars = new Calendar[2];
        calendars[0]= calendar;
        calendars[1]= calendar2;

        String s1 ="";

        String s2 = sdf.format(calendar1.getTimeInMillis());

        for (int i = 0; i < calendars.length; i++) {
            s1 = sdf.format(calendars[i].getTimeInMillis());
        }

        Log.i("What's inside",s1+"");
        Log.i("What's inside 2: ",s2+"");

        if (s1.equals(s2))
        {
            Log.i("Over here","properly");
            return false;

        }
        else {
            return true;
        }




    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mYear);
        dest.writeInt(mMonth);
        dest.writeInt(mDayOfWeek);
    }


    public static final Parcelable.Creator<DaysOutOfValidate> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DaysOutOfValidate>() {

        @Override
        public DaysOutOfValidate createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new DaysOutOfValidate(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public DaysOutOfValidate[] newArray(int size) {
            return new DaysOutOfValidate[size];
        }
    };
}
```

In DaysOutOfValidate are many wrong line but most impornant is method "isValid" which return true if the date is the same as the given date. I can't find how excatly work isValid but what I noticed that works like loop but I can't give more than one date cous of when I give more than one date like in example i give 16 November 2023 and 10 November 2023 only the last would disabled (10 november 2023), I know why it's happend like that but I don't know how to go around it. How to make to give some random dates and disable them in Calendar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method you are using now, only the last date is assigned to the **s1** variable while looping in the **isValid()** function and only this date is disable.

I changed the **isValid()** function by using **Calendar**. I also added two new methods. When I try it in my own locale, it works smoothly. I hope it works for you too.

```
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(long date) {
            Calendar calendarInput = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarInput.setTimeInMillis(date);

            for (Calendar blockedDate : getBlockedDates()) {
                if (areSameDay(calendarInput, blockedDate)) {
                    return false; // If it matches one of the blocked dates, return false.
                }
            }

            return true; // If there is no match, the date is valid.
        }

        private List<Calendar> getBlockedDates() {
            List<Calendar> blockedDates = new ArrayList<>();
            Calendar nov10 = Calendar.getInstance();
            nov10.set(2023, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 10);
            blockedDates.add(nov10);

            Calendar nov16 = Calendar.getInstance();
            nov16.set(2023, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 16);
            blockedDates.add(nov16);

            return blockedDates;
        }

        private boolean areSameDay(Calendar cal1, Calendar cal2) {
            return cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
                    cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        }
```

[image: DatePicker Screenshot]